# Spring Entitymanager java.lang.ClassFormatError

Tags: spring, hibernate, datasource, entitymanager

This is 2nd day that I am struggling with this issue.
We have a web app that uses spring and hibernate. Now We are trying to expose some functionality to command line. So We should be able to run a class from command line(without web app) so it should have access to spring and hibernate.

```
<context:annotation-config/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.x.y.z"/>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.x.y" />


<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">NONE</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
            <property name="database" value="SQL_SERVER" />
            <property name="showSql" value="false" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Here I am using [LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.html) but it seems there is no way to set datasource to it. It gets from persistance.xml

If I use [LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html) I can set datasource(it has datasource property)

persistance.xml:

```
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="oms-jpa">
    <class>com.domain.User</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

In persistance.xml I am not defining any database informaton for datasource, so LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean does not work for this.

what I am getting:

```
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file [C:\Users\ekamoliddinov\IdeaProjects\web\conf\spring-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/validation/Validation
```

googled then some says:

- Jar versions messed up
- jee-api.jar is missing

But I have jee-api.jar.

My questions:

- What is causing the above exception?
- Can I use `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` without having web
  container? Spec does not say anything about this.
- If i can not use `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` then how can I set up
  LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean so it should use my datasource not from
  persistance.xml(I can not define anything in persistance.xml).

I am using spring version 3.1.3 with hibernate 4.1.8.Final and i am in command line(I do no have jee environment)

Sorry about more than one questions, but all questions are arising from the same root I think.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying 3 days I fixed the issue. The jars where messed up :)
It was because I have jee-api.jar in my classpath and I was running the code from command line, I had not web env. So there was not any impl of jee-api.jar in my env. That is why it was giving the above exception. I removed jee-api.jar and disappeared.

Another thing That I can tell: we can use `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` from command line. I am using it.

The last thing: We can not set datasource to `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean`

This my help to someone.